# HR tag not moving below image

Tags: html, css

I wasn't sure exactly what to title the issue as I have no idea what's causing it or what may be so this one may be difficult to answer but anyone taking time just to look at the code would be greatly appreciated.

This is the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b73CA.jpg

I want the hr tag to be below the last image and not through the image like the tag above but I'm clueless.

Going to past the code into a fiddle for anyone wishing to help,many thanks.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tp76y660/

```
all code in fiddle, sorry for being inconvenient
```

Comment: You should take some time to narrow down the code to the problem area instead of saying you won't post it at all (a SO no-no). Often this step alone will help you isolate the problem. Also, your HTML has all sorts of issues (syntax errors, repeated IDs, etc.).

Comment: I didn't want to miss anything out that could cause an issue, I'll give it a try now though thanks. Code has been narrowed down largely

Comment: In the future try to reproduce any issues from scratch before posting here. 9 times out of 10 you’ll discover the answer in the process of isolating the problem and if you didn’t find it, posting the isolated issue here will make it much much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: 100%` to your hr’s.

For example:

```css
hr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using the css "clear" property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

```
hr {
  clear: both;
  }
```

or give the hr a style:

```
<hr class="mystyle"/>
```

and then style in css with:

```
hr.mystyle {
  clear: both;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at your code, you seem to be using:
`min-width: 400px;
 max-width: 960px;`
Which can be changed to:
`width: 100%`
So now the width of the `<hr>` is the total width of its parent container.